# How to use AOP on spring integration gateways?

Tags: spring-integration, spring-aop

I would like to intercept all spring integration gateways via AOP.

Is it possible to do that? If not what might be best way to do log input object coming to gateway?

```
@ContextConfiguration
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@DirtiesContext
public class AdviceExample {

  @Autowired
  private TestGateway testGateway;

  @Test
  public void testIt() {
    System.out.println(this.testGateway.testIt("foo"));
  }


  @MessagingGateway
  public interface TestGateway {

    @Gateway(requestChannel = "testChannel")
    @CustomAnnotation
    String testIt(String payload);

  }

  @Configuration
  @EnableIntegration
  @IntegrationComponentScan
  @EnableMessageHistory
  @EnableAspectJAutoProxy
  public static class ContextConfiguration {
    LoggingHandler logger = new LoggingHandler(LoggingHandler.Level.INFO.name());

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow testFlow() {
      return IntegrationFlows.from("testChannel")
                             .transform("payload.toUpperCase()")
                             .channel("testChannel")
                             .transform("payload.concat(' Manoj')")
                             .channel("testChannel")
                             .handle(logger)
                             .get();
    }

    @Bean
    public GatewayAdvice gtwyAdvice(){
      return new GatewayAdvice();
    }

  }

  @Retention(value = RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
  @Target(value = ElementType.METHOD)
  @Inherited
  public @interface CustomAnnotation{

  }

  @Aspect
  public static class GatewayAdvice {

    @Before("execution(* advice.AdviceExample.TestGateway.testIt(*))")
    public void beforeAdvice() {
        System.out.println("Before advice called...");
    }

    @Before("@annotation(advice.AdviceExample.CustomAnnotation)")
    public void beforeAnnotationAdvice() {
      System.out.println("Before annotation advice called...");
  }
  }

}
```

Comment: Please, be  more specific. Share some PoC on the matter. I'm afraid to go wrong way in my answer. Although it might be useful in some other place...

Comment: I want to do some common business logic before and after the gateways invoked.

Comment: Which gateways? HTTP, JMS, JDBC? Or just those which are based on the proxying for interfaces?

Comment: Custom gateways which we are creating using @Gateway..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do that. Take a look to the standard [Spring AOP Framework](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#aop-introduction). Since all those `@Gateway` are beans in the end you can add for them any `Advice` by their bean names and for the specific method, if that. For example we often suggest to use `@Transactional` on gateway's methods. And this is exactly a sample "how to use AOP on integration gateway".

Comment: Thank you, it works, but annotation style advice not working. If you see my code above beforeAnnotationAdvice  is not getting called, but beforeAdvice is called. This is because, annotations are not inheritable?